# Dynamically Change Theme in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, themes

I am tring to change theme based on switching css files dynamically.

```
@if (ViewBag.Theme == 1)
{
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/dark-theme.css" />
}
else
{
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
}
```

and in Shared/_layout.cshtml file :

```
@if (ViewBag.Theme == 1)
{
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-dark" data-bs-theme="dark">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            //....
        </div>
        <div class="d-flex form-check form-switch justify-content-end mx-lg-3">
            <input class="btn" type="button" onclick="changeLight()" value="Light">
        </div>
    </nav>
}
else
{
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light bg-white border-bottom box-shadow mb-3">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            //....
        </div>
        <div class="d-flex form-check form-switch justify-content-end mx-lg-3">
            <input class="btn" type="button" onclick="changeDark()" value="Dark">
        </div>
    </nav>
}
```

and via javascript and jquery :

```
function changeDark() {
    $.get(`@Url.Action("ToDark", "Home")`, function(data) {
        location.reload()
    })
}

function changeLight() {
    $.get(`@Url.Action("ToLight", "Home")`, function (data) {
        location.reload()
    })
}
```

and from the controller :

```
        [HttpGet]
        public void ToDark()
        {
            ViewBag.Theme = 1;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public void ToLight()
        {
            ViewBag.Theme = 0;
        }
```

My idea is _layout page is not reloading again. Just renderin body. How can ı solve this issue?

Comment: I dont know why but I change `TempData["Theme"]` instead of `ViewBag.Theme` and worked.